# как можно пробросить директорию из удаленного сервака в rancher?

Tags: docker, mount

Доброго времени суток! 
На сервисе rancher запущен контейнер, есть необходимость пробросить на него директорию которая находится на удаленном сервере. Может кто нибудь делал похожие вещи, поделитесь пожалуйста, чем это можно реализовать?

Comment: `VPN` пробовали поднимать?

Comment: чем vpn может помочь? 
мне нужно как-то сделать mount cifs драйвером.

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что на линукс машине нужно монтировать диск удаленной windows машины?

Comment: Совершенно верно.
Почитав подробнее об этом узнал, что в контейнере по умолчанию нельзя монтировать. Но это можно обойти запустив контейнер с флагом --privileged или добавив в dcoker-compose: cap_add: -  SYS_ADMIN 
      - DAC_READ_SEARCH
    security_opt:
      - apparmor:unconfined

Answer (score 0):

Так же, чтобы не создавать новый стэк, можно внести изменения в launchConfig через rancher-API, на одном уровне с capAdd, можно добавить 
`"securityOpt": [
"apparmor:unconfined"
],`